# Undetermined Progress bar in Win32 API

Tags: winapi, win32gui

How do I add Undetermined Progress Bar in win32 api?

I just want the animation/progress bar to display as a child to main window when a button is press, continue animation until the the button is again played and then dissapear.

Comment: using plain win32 api? or some framework?

Comment: @evilruff Plain Win32 Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just wish to show a small dialog containing an animated GIF file. You'll find plenty of example GIFs on the Internet.

http://www.ajaxload.info/ looks good.

Answer (score 5):

The standard [Win32 ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760818.aspx) control has a [Marquee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760816.aspx#Marquee_Style) mode for that exact purpose.